# Instalation of ar_pose

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

could you tell me, is it possible to use [ar_pose](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_pose) on Indigo?

Where I can find updated and stable version of this package?

Before I use catkin_make I have to download cv_bridge and other dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197915/instalation-of-ar_pose/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can use Max Schwarz's fork of the package ar_tools at github (make sure to get the **catkin** branch)  which compiles and works fine on hydro, might work fine in indigo as well:

https://github.com/xqms/ar_tools/tree/catkin

---

Originally posted by [Francisco Vina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2813/francisco-vina/) with karma: 101 on 2014-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-11-21**:
Thank you so much for you answer!